# Ruby Geocoded by in different languages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps, geocoding

I am using the geocoder gem to convert user input to longitude and latidude as well as getting the city and country names.

I am wondering: Is there a possibility to set the output language to another language than english? It seems for example that the city names are converted in english for non-german cities. Can I force geocoder to use german all the time?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this setting global add `Geocoder.configure language: :de` somewhere in initializer, for example

```
# config/initializers/geocoder.rb
Geocoder.configure language: :de
```

Or to make it per-model setting add `language: :de` to geocoder macro call

```
reverse_geocoded_by :latitude, :longitude, language: :de
```

Comment: Thanks! For some reason, it works only sometimes and it looks kind of random when it uses German and when it uses english...